# quick way to checkout (revert workspace changes) for most but not all files?

Tags: git

tl;dr: **what will happen if I stage a file and then run `git checkout .`?**

Here's the situation. I have an existing directory that I want to "merge" with the contents of a git repo (and integrate it with the repo).

I will do this by copying over the `.git` directory, this moves the repo but not the files, so i can do a sane manual "merge".

The `git status` will show a large number of "deleted" files. I want to `git checkout` these deleted files in a quick way but I also want to exclude a few of the "modified" files to keep their current filesystem contents.

So... I can run `git checkout` on all the ones I want to copy over, but is there a quicker way?

Maybe...

1. stage (`git add`) the modified files I wanna keep, then run `git checkout .`
2. use the original place that I cloned to (where i copied the `.git/` dir out of and use the file explorer to copy over the files to replace (still requires picking them out though)

So i guess the question boils down to "does git checkout affect staged files"?

---

The rest of the question is just a hugely extraneous background situational explanation.

So I'm on a windows machine and I want to integrate my Sublime Text 3 User package git repo which was set up from OS X.

So I go checkout my sublime-text-3-user-package repo from github:

(MSYS bash shell)

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/my-st3-user-package
cp -r my-st3-user-package/.git ~/AppData/Roaming/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User
```

Now in my User dir I can see all the missing files and I gotta reconcile them.

I do so for `Preferences.sublime-settings`, and it looks like this now.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    .gitignore
#       deleted:    Default (OSX).sublime-keymap
#       deleted:    GitGutter.sublime-settings
#       deleted:    Gitconfig.JSON-tmLanguage
#       deleted:    Gitconfig.tmLanguage
#       modified:   Package Control.sublime-settings
#       deleted:    README.md
#       deleted:    Shell-Unix-Generic.sublime-settings
#       deleted:    SublimeLinter.sublime-settings
#       deleted:    Tomorrow-Night-Eighties.tmTheme
#       deleted:    movemultiplelines.py
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       Package Control.ca-bundle
#       Package Control.ca-list
#       Package Control.cache/
#       Package Control.last-run
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I want to bring back all of these files except for `Package Control.sublime-settings`.

Comment: I'd say this is where a GUI frontend shines.

Comment: GUI frontends aren't portable though. Once I know how to do this once I know how to do this forever.

Comment: "Portable"?! Unless you're writing a script that's a weird rationale, it's not like you switch between them daily. If you prefer the CLI, serve yourself, but it's a preference, you don't need to convince me that mine is wrong. (FWIW I'd bet dollars to donuts that most GUI clients have this in the right-click menu for the changed files list.)

Comment: I switch between OS X and Linux and Windows and iOS and Android daily. Sometimes hourly. Guess what, the only *possible* interface portable across them is the terminal. Besides, I wasn't rejecting your comment, I agree that many Git frontends help with this sort of thing. But it sure doesn't answer the question (which was "how do you do this with the git cli")... But it's not like you put it as an answer (boy that'd be a bad answer) so i can't complain about that either. In fact I wasn't really complaining either. So yeah no hard feelings

Comment: The problem with GUIs is that they usually abstract away too much understanding of how Git actually works. It's good to be proficient with Git from the command line.

Comment: Yeah, i mean it's hard enough to get yourself back to a clean state once you mess up your git repo by doing something silly. I couldn't even imagine how to deal with those situations if your GUI doesn't show you the right options. Probably end up deleting it and cloning it to start fresh and lose your work. Which by the way has *never* happened to me, because git is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This was a stupid question because I could have tested it like I just did.

Option 1 works exactly as I hoped it would.  Stage it, then checkout. the staged file stays put.

Comment: Git is great for this (in most cases), just try something out and see what happens...you can usually undo the change. For dangerous things (like `filter-branch`), just make a cheap practice repo with a few practice commits. Or make a backup clone, which is also quite easy to do with Git.